# select all customers which have no services

Tags: sql, mysql

I have two MySQL tables, `tblclients` and `tblservices`. Each record in `tblservices` represents a service we provide for a client and there can be many services per client. Both tables have a 'status' field, in `tblclients` it is either 'active' or 'inactive' and in `tblservices` it is either 'active' or 'terminated'.

I need to write a SQL statement which will output a list of active clients which have no active services so that I can write a php script which will make the clients inactive.

I understand how to list all clients which have a service which is terminated, but I don't understand how to list clients which have no active services (all terminated). Is there a way to query this in SQL using subqueries or the like. So far I have:

```
SELECT tblclients.id, tblclients.email, tblservices.status 
FROM tblclients JOIN tblservices on tblclients.id = tblservices.userid 
WHERE tblclients.status="active" AND tblservices.status="terminated";
```

Comment: Do you need customers who have never had any service at all?

Comment: No, clients with no services should not be included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [WHERE [NOT] EXISTS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) (I've munged your table names for readability):

```
SELECT * FROM clients WHERE
    clients.status = 'active' AND
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM services WHERE
        services.userid = clients.id AND
        services.status = 'active'
    );
```

This'll give you all your active clients that don't have any active services (these will include clients with no services at all).

Hope this helps!

**Update:** To exclude clients with no services at all, just add that condition, too:

```
SELECT * FROM clients WHERE
    clients.status = 'active' AND
    EXISTS (SELECT * FROM services WHERE services.userid = clients.id) AND
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM services WHERE
        services.userid = clients.id AND
        services.status = 'active'
    );
```

Comment: How can we exclude clients with no services?

Comment: @Mitchell  You can just add a "if services exist for this client" clause to the query; I've updated my answer to include this.

Comment: Just a quick note to say that I marked this answer as correct not because it is the most correct but because it made the most sense to me. I have no idea whether the other answers were more or less efficient queries.

Answer (score 0):

Change your join to a LEFT JOIN and set a filter for null tblservices.userid.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming tblServices has no records with that client's id....

```
SELECT tblclients.id, tblclients.email, tblservices.status 
FROM tblclients 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblservices on tblclients.id = tblservices.userid 
WHERE tblservices.id is null
```

Feel free to use any field in tblservices for the null test, though I think the id for that table would be best.

If you need to show that as 0 services as a count, use a case statement.